# Akka Streams Accumulate by Source Single

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to use akka streams to accumulate data and use as batch:

```scala
val myFlow: Flow[String, Unit, NotUsed] = Flow[String].collect {
    case record =>
      println(record)
      Future(record)
  }.mapAsync(1)(x => x).groupedWithin(3, 30 seconds)
    .mapAsync(10)(records =>
      someBatchOperation(records))
    )
```

My expectation from code above was not make any operation until 3 records are ready, or 30 seconds pass. But when I send some request with `Source.single("test")`, it is processing this record without waiting for others or 30 seconds.

How can I use this flow to wait for other records to came or 30 seconds idle?

Record is coming from an API request one by one and I am trying to accumulate this data in flow like:

```scala
Source.single(apiRecord).via(myFlow).runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually does that. Let's consider the following:

```
Source(Stream.from(1)).throttle(1, 400 milli).groupedWithin(3, 1 seconds).runWith(Sink.foreach(i => println(s"Done with ${i} ${System.currentTimeMillis}")))
```

The output of that line, until I killed the process, was:

```
Done with Vector(1, 2, 3) 1599495716345
Done with Vector(4, 5) 1599495717348
Done with Vector(6, 7, 8) 1599495718330
Done with Vector(9, 10) 1599495719350
Done with Vector(11, 12, 13) 1599495720330
Done with Vector(14, 15) 1599495721350
Done with Vector(16, 17, 18) 1599495722328
Done with Vector(19, 20) 1599495723348
Done with Vector(21, 22, 23) 1599495724330
```

As we can see, the time differences between every time we emit 2 elements, to 3 elements, is a bit more than 1 second. That makes sense because after the 1 second delay, it took a bit more to get to the printing line.

The difference between every time we emit 2 elements, to 3 elements, is less than a second. Because it had enough elements to go on.

Why didn't it work in your example?

When you are using `Source.single`, then the source adds a complete stage to itself. You can see it in the [source code of akka](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/fusing/GraphStages.scala#L276).
In this case, the `groupedWithin` flow knows that it won't get any more elements, so it can emit the `"test"` string. In order to actually test this flow try to create a bigger stream.

When using Source(1 to 10) it actually translates into `Source.Single`, which completes the stream as well. We can see that [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala#L360).

Comment: But after removing the throttle, the flow will complete immediately. Can you explain why?

Comment: @YikSanChan If we remove the throttle, so we hit only the 3 numbers limit, which will happen all the time. The throttle is only here to help us see that both thresholds are hit. 400 millis is an amount of time that sometimes 3 can happen in the same second, and sometimes it can't

Comment: Thank you for your eforts but throttling is not saving my proplem directly. My record is coming from api one by one and i am sending incoming data to flow. I want to accumulate those records until their count is exceed or time is up but while i am using `source.single` it is not accumalating in somewhere in flow.

Comment: As explained in my post, that is not possible. I'll repeat: When using `Source.single`, the completion stage is added to the source. The flow knows that it won't get any more elements, so it emits what it has. In addition, there is no sense in sending 1 element and trying to accumulate 3. How do you even expect that? You should have one Source, receiving all of your elements, and than accumulate those.